# SOCKET_RWGROUP=postfix in ClamAv?

Tags: sockets, nginx, postfix-mta

I have read the guides about install postfix on the server and there is written to set the parameter: SOCKET_RWGROUP = postfix in the file / etc / default / clamav-milter but I installed ClamAV and unfortunately I do not have such a file. How do I set it up?

I have followed the instructions on the page: https://greenqloud.zendesk.com/entries/74986716-How-To-Make-your-e-mail-Truly-Green-Part-2-fighting-spam

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions this is now handled in /etc/clamav/clamav-milter.conf. Change the line:
`MilterSocketGroup clamav`
to
`MilterSocketGroup postfix`